# Nested resource wont create data, rollback transaction right after begin transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

My problem is that a tag wont be created which is nested in posts.

I have Post which have tags nested in them. Like this

```
resources :posts do
  resources :tags, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

In my tags controller i have this

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @tag = Tag.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @tag = @post.tags.build(params[:tags])

    if @tag.save 
      flash[:notice] = "Tag created"
      redirect_to @tag.post
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not add tag at this time"
      redirect_to @tag.post
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@post, @tag] do |f| %>
  <% if @tag.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@tag.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this tag from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @tag.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :tagable_type, :placeholder => "Type" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :tagable_id, :placeholder => "Id" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Tag model

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post_id, :user_id, :tagable_type, :tagable_id

  validates :post_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :tagable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :link, :thumbnail, :title, :user_id, :youtube, :youtube_id, :website_name, :image_field

  default_scope order: 'posts.active DESC'

  has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :user
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Now i can create a tag but the tagable_type and tagable_id fields are not being created for some reaseon

```
Started POST "/posts/18/tags" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-26 15:54:14 +0200
Processing by TagsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gwpTs0Qqcrre4tH974RrfpaENGZKtSbkJx2U0H67AcM=", "tag"=>{"tagable_type"=>"Player", "tagable_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create Tag", "post_id"=>"18"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? ORDER BY posts.active DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "18"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("created_at", "post_id", "tagable_id", "tagable_type", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 26 Jun 2013 13:54:14 UTC +00:00], ["post_id", 18], ["tagable_id", nil], ["tagable_type", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 26 Jun 2013 13:54:14 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
   (6.9ms)  commit transaction
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 18 ORDER BY posts.active DESC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/18
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)
```

Comment: you could debug your error by printing in your server console with `p @tag.errors` or `p @tag.errors.full_messages`.

Comment: Now i can create a tag, but the field for tagable_type and tagable_id are not being created even tho i type in two valuse in the form field

Comment: Please provide the model up there thanks

Comment: In my create action i had @tag = @post.tags.build(params[:tags]), should be tag inside params instead of tags. sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the `create()` action of your `TagsController`:

```rb
@tag = @post.tags.build(params[:tags])
```

The hash used to create the tag should be `params[:tag]`, not `params[:tags]`.